# Trouble transforming a data set in R; making a look up table

Tags: r, matrix, reshape, transpose, lookup-tables

R (programming language)

I would like to transform my data set that has sample numbers, treatment days and concentrations (variable); to set it up as a single matix where the cells are filed with only concentration values. My output is a lookup table, where the user can look up a sample number along the 1st row and a day along the first column (header), and follow these along to get a concentration.

This is not my data set (it comes as a matrix), however I quickly made these three for the example.

```
Samplenb - < c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4)
Day <- c(1,5,10,15,1,5,10,15,1,5,10,15,1,5,10,15)
Concentration <- c(0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.9,0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.9,0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.9,0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.9)
```

Any help it much appreciated. I have been playing around with the reshape package functions. However, they do not seem suitable.

Thank you for taking the time to help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For variety (and since you mentioned "reshape"), here are a few options (though MrFlick's is by far the most appropriate).

The first two options assume we have grouped your vectors into a `data.frame`:

```
DF <- data.frame(Samplenb, Day, Concentration)
```

Option 1: `reshape`

```
reshape(DF, direction = "wide", idvar = "Day", timevar = "Samplenb")
#   Day Concentration.1 Concentration.2 Concentration.3 Concentration.4
# 1   1             0.2             0.2             0.2             0.2
# 2   5             0.3             0.3             0.3             0.3
# 3  10             0.5             0.5             0.5             0.5
# 4  15             0.9             0.9             0.9             0.9
```

Option 2: `dcast` from "reshape2"

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(DF, Day ~ Samplenb, value.var="Concentration")
#   Day   1   2   3   4
# 1   1 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2
# 2   5 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3
# 3  10 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5
# 4  15 0.9 0.9 0.9 0.9
```

Option 3: A manual approach--should be fast, but unless you're a coding masochist, best left as a lesson in matrix indexing in R.

```
Nrow <- unique(Day)
Ncol <- unique(Samplenb)
M <- matrix(0, nrow = length(Nrow), ncol = length(Ncol), 
            dimnames = list(Nrow, Ncol))
M[cbind(match(Day, rownames(M)), match(Samplenb, colnames(M)))] <- Concentration
#      1   2   3   4
# 1  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2
# 5  0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3
# 10 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5
# 15 0.9 0.9 0.9 0.9
```

Answer (score 2):

Good ol' `xtabs` can help out here

```
xtabs(Concentration ~ Day + Samplenb)
```

will produce

```
    Samplenb
Day    1   2   3   4
  1  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2
  5  0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3
  10 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5
  15 0.9 0.9 0.9 0.9
```